# FPDF does not save php post data in the pdf file

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

I'm trying to generate a pdf file using FPDF with php. I send post data to the script and these data are displayed correctly in the pdf page before saving it. when I save it I get blank cells in the pdf file which are saved by post data while static text is saved normally.

```
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);
for($x=0; $x<count($_POST['cat_name']); $x++){
  $pdf->Cell(40,10,$_POST['cat_name'][$x],1,0,'L');
  $pdf->Cell(40,10,$_POST['cat_code'][$x],1,0,'L');
  $pdf->Cell(40,10,$_POST['total_amount'][$x],1,1,'L');
}
```

Before saving data is displayed correctly. Just heading is static

[image]

But in the pdf file these cells are blank

[image]

So how to fix this issue to save php post data in the file?

Comment: This link might help http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/output.htm, if not can you show the full scripts

Comment: Thanks @Khem $pdf->Output('D','myfile.pdf'); solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Saving the file directly using this code solved the problem

```
$pdf->Output('D','myfile.pdf');
```

Thanks to Khem for the hint